# Laravel 4 Fluent count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using the Laravel 4 php framework and I need to use the fluent query builder to get some statistical type data.
I have a database table with a structure like the follwing

```
id: int
group_id: int
sent_at: datetime
message_id: int
```

I need a fluent query that will get the count of all rows that have the same message id, and I want to also have that count organized by the group_id.

For example, I have a message id of 1, and each row with the message id of 1 has a group id that may or may not be the same. I need to know what group id's there are in the table for a given message id, and also how many total there is for each group id.

I hope that makes sense.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And this is the Laravel 4 version:

```php
$message_id = 1;

// You can change "amount" to anything that best suits you
// The `orderBy` line is not necessary, but I'm assuming you will may need it.
$groups = DB::table('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')
    ->select(array('group_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) `amount`')))
    ->where('message_id', '=', $message_id)
    ->groupBy('group_id')
    ->orderBy('amount', 'DESC')
    ->get();

foreach ($groups as $g) {
    echo "$g->group_id has $g->amount messages with id $message_id";
}
```

Comment: what is the `amount` after the count for?,   also I think I'm seeing a syntax error, not enough closing parenthesises in the select clause

Comment: You were right about the syntax error. I've fixed it. The `amount` tells SQL to name the column "amount", which then translates to `$g->amount` on the loop. You can name it anything you want.

Answer (score -2):

Try that query for getting count of group_id for each message_id:

```
SELECT message_id, count(group_id) FROM table GROUP BY message_id
```

To get it for given message_id just use "WHERE":

```
SELECT message_id, count(group_id) FROM table WHERE message_id = XX GROUP BY message_id
```

To get all group_id for given message_id, just use simple query like that:

```
SELECT group_id FROM table WHERE message_id = XX
```

If that's not what you were looking for, let me know - we'll work on correct one :)

(Of course change "table" to your table name)

EDIT: Fluent version example to get count of group_id for message_id = 1:

```
$query = DB::table('table')
->select(array('message_id', DB::raw('COUNT(group_id) as group_count')))
->where('message_id', '=', 1)
->group_by('message_id')
->get();
```

Comment: OP asked for a fluent query, not raw SQL.

Comment: True, here's fluent version for count of group_id for given message_id:

`$query = DB::table('table')->select(array('message_id', DB::raw('COUNT(group_id) as group_count')))->where('message_id', '=', 1)->group_by('message_id')->get();`

Comment: @MichałPrajsnar, can you rewrite your answer to be more objective. Maybe you can show up the fluent query before the raw SQL, or simple remove the SQL query if it is not relevant. I will upvote your answer if you improve it.